# How should I create a batch file (.bat) from command I executed in CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Below command is working fine in command prompt but I am having difficulties in creating a .bat file so that i can schedule it. Please help.

```
E:\ExportPackage.exe -profile  "SASAdmin" -package \Promotion_package_from_PROD\Package_1" -objects  "/Shared Data" -since "Week to date" -modified -subprop
```

Comment: What difficulties are you having?

Comment: The command which you state 'is working fine' in the Command Prompt has imbalanced double quotes, as does the example posted by Sam Denty.

Comment: Please see [ask] for help on asking a useful question which will attract good answers.

Answer (score 0):

To create a batch-file in the command prompt, simply `echo` it to a `.bat` file. For example typing this into the command prompt:

```
(echo @echo off&echo E:\ExportPackage.exe -profile  "SASAdmin" -package \Promotion_package_from_PROD\Package_1" -objects  "/Shared Data" -since "Week to date" -modified -subprop&pause) > test.bat
```

**test.bat:**

```
@echo off
E:\ExportPackage.exe -profile  "SASAdmin" -package \Promotion_package_from_PROD\Package_1" -objects  "/Shared Data" -since "Week to date" -modified -subprop
pause
```